# Assigning objects to an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

I am quite new to c++ and have been struggling on a part of an assignment for the last week.

I know it's a simple thing but I can't wrap my head around the right way to go about it.

I need to create four objects for the class (Employee) that I've made and assign them to the array I've made

heres my default constructor:

```
Employee() // Deafault Constructor 
    {
        empNumber = 00000;
        hours, payRate = 0;
        name = "Name";
    }
```

And my attempt to create 4 objects with different data saved into the array elements:

```
int Employees[4];
    Employees[0] = Employee(67258, 40, 35, "Craig");
    Employees[1] = Employee(25387, 30, 20, "Carol");
    Employees[2] = Employee(11945, 38, 30, "Suzie");
    Employees[3] = Employee(90832, 28, 40, "Sam");
```

Like I said, basically brand new and I've been googling up a storm to no avail.

Any help or suggestions or even links are welcome!

Here's my whole code:

```
class Employee
{
private:

    int empNumber;
    string name;
    double hours, payRate;

public:

    Employee() // Deafault Constructor 
    {
        empNumber = 00000;
        hours = 0;
        payRate = 0;
        name = "Name";
    }

    Employee(int e_empNumber, double e_hours, double e_payRate, string e_name) // Non-Default Constructor
    {
        empNumber = e_empNumber;
        hours = e_hours;
        payRate = e_payRate;
        name = e_name;
    }

    void getEmployeeData()
    {
        cout << "Employee #: " << empNumber << ' ';
        cout << "Name: " << name << ' ';
        cout << "Hours worked: " << hours << ' ';
        cout << "Pay Rate: " << payRate << endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    int Employees[4];
    Employees[0] = Employee(67258, 40, 35, "Craig");
    Employees[1] = Employee(25387, 30, 20, "Carol");
    Employees[2] = Employee(11945, 38, 30, "Suzie");
    Employees[3] = Employee(90832, 28, 40, "Sam");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[and the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIiXO.png)

Comment: Note that `hours, payRate = 0;` only assigns `0` to the second variable, `hours` remains uninitialized.

Comment: Can you show us your code (see [mcve]) and the exact error message you get?

Comment: You have an array of int and you are trying to insert the type Employee. They are not the same thing

Comment: it's all I know, googling now    - Wow @Amedeus, your comment helped so much, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do that to create and fill the employees:

```
Employe employees[4];
    employees[0] = Employee(67258, 40, 35, "Craig");
    employees[1] = Employee(25387, 30, 20, "Carol");
    employees[2] = Employee(11945, 38, 30, "Suzie");
    employees[3] = Employee(90832, 28, 40, "Sam");
```

What you did is just creating an array of ints.
Here you see how to do it:

```
Type variable_name[size];
```

Comment: Ya! The comment from Amedeus helped me figure it out! Thank you for showing me too!  This is great its been stressing me out all week!

Comment: Happy it helped. Please select an answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone! I got it working to the specifications!

Here's my final code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;




class Employee
{
private:

    int empNumber;
    string name;
    double hours, payRate;

public:

    Employee() // Deafault Constructor 
    {
        empNumber = 00000;
        hours = 0;
        payRate = 0;
        name = "Name";
    }

    Employee(int e_empNumber, double e_hours, double e_payRate, string e_name) // Non-Default Constructor
    {
        empNumber = e_empNumber;
        hours = e_hours;
        payRate = e_payRate;
        name = e_name;

        void getEmployeeData();
        {
            cout << "Employee #: " << empNumber << " - ";
            cout << "Name: " << name << " - ";
            cout << "Hours worked: " << hours << " - ";
            cout << "Pay Rate: " << payRate << endl;
        }
    }



};

int main()
{
    Employee Employees[4];
    Employees[0] = Employee(67258, 40, 35, "Craig");
    Employees[1] = Employee(25387, 30, 20, "Carol");
    Employees[2] = Employee(11945, 38, 30, "Suzie");
    Employees[3] = Employee(90832, 28, 40, "Sam");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {

        void getEmployeeData();
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This will cout the Employee data stored in the array

Comment: Very small recommendation: The class name is correct: Employee, but it is recommended to use the variable name Employees starting as a lower case: employees. These small things will help you distinguish between type names and variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of adding a bit more insight.

When you call this:

```
Employee Employees[4];
```

The default `ctor` will be called to initialize the array. So four objects are automatically created. Then when you do the assignments:

```
Employees[0] = Employee(67258, 40, 35, "Craig");
Employees[1] = Employee(25387, 30, 20, "Carol");
Employees[2] = Employee(11945, 38, 30, "Suzie");
Employees[3] = Employee(90832, 28, 40, "Sam");
```

Four new objects are created using the parameterized `ctor` which will replace the originally created four. So the original ones are useless (since they were never used) and are just made for waste.

You can verify what I said by adding the following:

To default `ctor`

```
cout << "default ctor" << endl;
```

To parameterized `ctor`

```
cout << "parameterized ctor" << endl;
```

If you want to avoid multiple construction of objects, you can use this:

```
Employee Employees[4] = {
  Employee(67258, 40, 35, "Craig"),
  Employee(25387, 30, 20, "Carol"),
  Employee(11945, 38, 30, "Suzie"),
  Employee(90832, 28, 40, "Sam")
};
```

This will not call the default `ctor` and will construct only four `Employee` objects.

Alternatively, you can use `std::vector` (`#include <vector>`) which gives you flexibility with size and does not use default `ctor` if you use `push_back` function.